# Is it possible to define enums without values with Python?

Tags: python, enums

One advantage of enums in Java and other languages is that I do not have to care about specific values (in contrast to constants/static final members). For example, in Java I can do the following:

```
public enum Color {
    RED, BLUE;
}
```

At least to my knowledge, in python I have to do the following:

```py
class Color(Enum) {
    RED = "red" # or e.g 1
    BLUE = "blue" # or e.g. 2
}
```

If I have an enum with hundreds of names, then this can get quite cumbersome, because I always have to keep track whether a value was already assigned to a name or not. Is it maybe possible to achieve the same result as in Java without resorting to generators or the like?

Comment: See https://docs.python.org/3/library/enum.html#using-automatic-values

Answer (score 31, accepted):

If you're using Python 3.6 or later, you can use `enum.auto()`:

```
from enum import Enum, auto

class Color(Enum):
    RED = auto()
    BLUE = auto()
```

The documentation for the [`enum`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/enum.html) library describes this and other useful features like the `@unique` decorator.

Comment: Wow, it can auto-count. Did they use AI for it?

Answer (score 29):

One way is to use the Enum base class as a [callable](https://docs.python.org/3/library/enum.html#functional-api):

```
Color = Enum('Color', 'RED BLUE GREEN ORANGE')
```

Comment: Is there a downside to this method?

Comment: Why would you expect downsides? This method is officially explained in the documentation that you linked, so it should be as good as the class syntax.

Comment: With this method you are not stuck with '=' which is closer to what is asked by the questions. I am also glad to see that Intellisence (pylance) manage to make a link between the Enum and the values

Comment: Well there is a small downside, Intellisence (pylance) does work but you need to dig your param in the available options. With the @Greg Hewgill option, you don't have this issue but you are stuck again with '= ...'

Answer (score 3):

The answer from Daniel Roseman is an elegant solution, that is in line with the official documentation and that should be appropriate in most cases.

Only for completeness here are a few other options.

```
class Color(Enum):
    RED, BLUE = range(2)
```

This will even work without the enum package.

```
class Color:
    RED, BLUE = range(2)
```

But this solution has some drawbacks. For example if you print Color.RED, you don't see the name, but the number.

In principle an enum is just a list of constants. So even the following works if you completely define it without a surrounding class.

```
RED, BLUE = range(2)
```

I don't want to discuss the advantages and disadvantages of this. There may be specific uses cases of such code.

Note: It must be said here, that `range(2)` starts counting at 0. So the first value, when used as a boolean expression is evaluated to False. This is normally not, what someone wants. It could be a nice feature in very specific situations (if your first value is intentionally something like `INVALID` or `UNDEFINED`). But normally it should be better to use `range(1,3)` instead of `range(2)`.